# flutter GridView.builder rotation

Tags: flutter, gridview

I have gridview with horizontal direction. Currently builder create elements top to bottom but i want gridview create an elements to start from the bottom.

```
 GridView.builder(
                                reverse: false,
                                gridDelegate:
                                    new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisCount: 5,
                                  crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                                  mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                                ),

                                //dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
                                itemCount: koltuklar.length,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                primary: false,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                //dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                                  return Container(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: Text(koltuklar[index]
                                          .nKoltukNo
                                          .toString()));
                                }),
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with GridView.builder constructor but you can simply hack. You can use RotatedBox to hack, I made an example for you.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: 3,
              child: GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 5,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                ),
                itemCount: koltuklar.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(koltuklar[index]
                          .nKoltukNo
                          .toString()));
                },
              ),
            ),
          )
```